# Magento 1.9.0.1 new product widget problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added in `cms/pages/home page` this automatic widget code :

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_products="all_products" show_paginator="0" products_per_page="8" products_count="8" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

[image]

But the list feel like unordered?

Answer (score 1):

add a `column_count` attribute to your widget declaration which specifies the number of columns to be used. In your case I think you need 3.

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_products="all_products" show_paginator="0" products_per_page="8" products_count="8" column_count="3" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```